# Admob : difference between RewardedAd and RewardedInterstitialAd?

Tags: java, android, ios, kotlin, admob

I don't manage to understand the difference between [RewardedAd](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded?hl=en) and [RewardedInterstitialAd](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-interstitial?hl=en).

I even tested the examples [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/main/java/admob) but I don't see a major difference between the projects 'RewardedInterstitialExample' and 'RewardedVideoExample'.

Anybody may give some explanations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the description mentioned in the [link](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-interstitial?hl=en) you have given regarding RewardedInterstitialAd, it states that:

> Rewarded interstitial is a type of incentivized ad format that lets you offer rewards for ads that appear automatically during natural app transitions. **Unlike rewarded ads, users aren't required to opt in to view a rewarded interstitial**.

Usually, interstitial ads are presented during the user's journey/movement through your application. As opposed to RewardedVideo ads that you present to the user when there is some context for him/her to view it.
I.E. you have a gaming application where the user has a certain amount of lives and when those lives are over, you present a RewardedVideo Ad to the user to get back another life so he/she can keep playing.

Comment: Thanks but what do they mean by "opt in". Does it mean that for a rewarded interstitial, you can display it directly without any explanatory alert before? It is not what occurs in their 'RewardedInterstitialExample' ; there is an explanatory alert before the rewarded interstitial. So both types of rewarded are managed in the same way in their examples.

Comment: @toto_tata - I tried explaining in my answer what opt in means. For a RewardedVideo ad, a user must explicitly choose to see one. For a RewardedInterstitialAd, that does not necessarily need to happen. Hope that clarifies things better. Also, if my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is clear. But Google example is not clear...